# Why does Ruby on Rails keep telling me about an uninstantiated variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

**EDIT: SOLVED**, view the solution in Brian Kunzig's answer+comments.

I've decided to try out Ruby on Rails and have been constantly running into this problem. I was searching around for problems like this but none of the solutions have done the trick for me. It seems that I constantly write a part of code that just isn't correct. So here are some code snippets:

(ignore what the code would be for, it's just to try stuff out)

My controller:

```
class AuthsController < ApplicationController

        def index
          @auths=Auth.all  
        end

        def new
          @auth=Auth.new
        end

        def show
          @auth=Auth.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

My index.html.erb:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:50%; text-align: center">
    <h1>Please authorise your use of this webpage and its database(s).</h1>
    <%= form_for :auth, url: auths_path do |f| %>

    <% if @auth.errors.any? %> ==> RAILS REPORTS ERROR IN CODE HERE
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@auth.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this authentification from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @auth.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

</div>
```

So, bottom line. Rails is saying that I cannot use @auth in the form_for block, for example. Or anywhere else for that matter.. It always says that it belongs to NilClass or something like that. It obviously wants me to instantiate it somehow, but isn't it enough to make the method new and put in the line: @auth=Auth.new ?

I'm just confused with this situation because I can't figure out how it's supposed to go. Thanks a lot !

P.S. I'm using `<%= form_for :auth, url: auths_path do |f| %>` because it won't accept @auth, that's what the error in the next line is. I have seen solutions to instantiate it "on the go" outside of the controller but I want to do it the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: Your `index` controller handler declares `@auths` only. Why on the Earth you expect `@auth` to be defined?

Comment: You should not have form content in index.html.erb file. please put the form code in new.html.erb file. index is for displaying the list of auth object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be putting this form in the `new.html.erb` file and not the `index`.  The `index` is for listing entries while the `new` and `create` actions handle `POST` requests.  You're getting an error because you're trying to list all Auth's when none have been created.  Also, you're sending a form via a `GET` request if you're using standard rails routing.  Use resourceful routing and put this form in your `new` view for that controller and it should work.

Routes file should be:

```
resources :auths
```

This will provide all the necessary routing automagically.  If you type `rake routes` after modifying this you will see the newly generated urls and the helpers to them.  You will notice it affords the `create` and `update` actions a `POST`/`PUT` request while others are `GET`.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I have made some projects where I have put the form in new.html.erb and it has functioned properly. Does it mean that a form HAS to be in the "new" template because of the routes ? I specifically want it to show up on the first thing that opens that's why it's in there.


EDIT: the resources:auths was already added to the routes file

Comment: @lmatejic not necessarily, but since you only define `@auth` in actions `new` and `show`, these are the only views you can use it in. Sometimes it's even viable to put a form into a partial (`_form`) and include it on pages where `@auth` is defined (`new` and `edit` most of the time).

Comment: I know how to create views and other methods, so how could I make the form the first thing that opens after let's say, a welcome page ? E.G. the page says Welcome ! and has a continue button underneath, then it takes you to a functional form without showing all the data that was entered before.

Comment: If you are using Rails standard resource routing then yes, it must go in the new action.  If you type "rake routes" in the console it will show you what routes and their request types were generated by that one resource.  The index action is predefined to submit your page via a 'get' request which means you would need to alter that to a POST request if you ever want to submit data via a form.

Comment: Make a link to the new action of that auth controller from your homepage.  In your hompe-page view do this:  
<%= link_to "Continue to Form", new_auth_path %>    and it will take them to the right page.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. So after making a link to the form in new.html.erb I should be able to use @auth in forms normally without having to do things "incorrectly" ?

Comment: Yep!  The reason you were getting an error was that you didn't have any objects created for the index action to list so it was basically saying there isn't anything here yet.  Once you do things via the method above, you will be good to go.

Comment: @BrianKunzig That fixed it. I was unaware that the routes had anything to do with actually handling different requests. I thought it's just for defining page display hierarchy or something like that if you can see where I'm coming from. I've been developing in C,C++, C# and Java, etc. so this is a totally new experience for me. Thanks a lot !